# Intro to Algorithms (chapter 1-1)

Tags: algorithm, big-o

Just reading this book for fun, this isn't homework.

However I am already confused on the first main assignment:

*1-1 Comparison of running times*

*For each function f(n) and time t in the following table, determine the largest size n of a problem that can be solved in time t, assuming that the algorithm to solve the problem takes f(n) microseconds.*

What does this even mean?

The next table shows a bunch of times along one axis (1 second, 1 minute, one hour, etc), and the other axis shows different f(n) such as lg n, sqrt(n), n, etc.

I am not sure how to fill in the matrix because I can't understand the question. So if f(n) = lg n, it's asking the largest n that can be solved in, for example, 1 second, but the problem takes f(n) = lg n microseconds to solve? What does that last part even mean? I don't even know how to set up the equations / ratios to solve this problem because I literally can't even put together the meaning of the question.

My hangup is over the sentence "assuming that the algorithm to solve the problem takes f(n) microseconds" because I don't know what this refers to. The time for *what* algorithm to solve *what* problem takes f(n) microseconds? So if I call f(100) it'll take lg 100 microseconds? So I need to find some n where f(n) = lg n microseconds = 1 second?

Does this mean lg n microseconds = 1 second when lg n microseconds = 10^6 microseconds, so n = 2^(10^6)?

Comment: I'm glad I'm not the only one. This is the third frustrating section I reach in this book :(

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For each time `T`, and each function `f(n)`, you are required to find the maximal integer `n` such that `f(n) <= T`

For example, `f(n) = n^2, T=1Sec = 1000 ms`:

```
n^2 <= 1000
n <= sqrt(1000)
n <= ~31.63 <- not an integer
n <= 31
```

Given any function `f(n)`, and some time `T`, you are required to similarly find the maximal value of `n`, and fill in the table.

Comment: @Aruka J. Also note that in this example @amit used `ms (millseconds)` instead of `μs (microseconds`).

Comment: This is the best explanation..... really well broken down esp for a programmer.... thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I will do the first two as an example to help you do the rest. Since a second is `10^6` microseconds. By solving an equation which relates `f(n)` to the time we are plotting for `f(n)` to run we can solve for the largest input `n` that `f` can run on within the time limit.

1 second:

```
log(n2)=1,000,000⟹n2=e1,000,000⟹n=e500,000
```

1 minute:

```
log(n2)=60,000,000⟹n2=e60,000,000⟹n=e30,000,000
```

the rest can be similarly done.

P.S. make sure to floor the values of n you get from these equations because n is an integer length input.